# C++ Find names in string vector that contains certain letters

Tags: c++, string, vector

Does anyone know a good way to find names in a C++ string vector that contains certain letters?

Let's say that I have a vector containing 100 names. Is there a way to find for example all names containing the character 't' like Tom, Peter, Jonathan etcetera?

To my understanding std::find would only find the name Jonathan if I search specifically for "Jonathan". Is there another method that one could use?

Comment: [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)?

Comment: Instead of `etcetera`, you should state the requirements.  Is casing important?  Multiple letters?

Answer (score 1):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition

```
auto it = std::partition(v.begin(), v.end(), [](std::string s) {
return ( s.find("t") != std::string::npos );
});
```